# Saving a file generated by AJAX script

Tags: php, ajax, concurrency, yii

Good evening.

I am using Yii framework and mPDF library to generate some PDF files via Ajax script and I need to force "save as" dialogue in users' browsers.

I know how to solve this issue with a single user dowloading a single file.
Does anyone have a tip on how could I make it all work on high-load system (e.g. several users trying to generate and download a PDF will attempt to access *one* temp file which would cause an error)?

Should I generate a separate file for each session? And which way would be nice for cleaning these temp files?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks guys, everything seems clear, going to try in the morning ^^

Comment: Solved it by creating temp files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `tempnam` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php to generate the temp files. they'll be uniquely named, so it'll be easy to make one per session. Just delete as normal when you're done with them.

Answer (score 1):

Make an invisible iframe. From JS set that iframe's src to the script on your server that generates the PDF.

```
 <iframe src="http://yoursite.com/download-file.php?report=pdf&param1=value1&param2=value2..." width="1" height="1"></iframe>
```

Then (and I'm not sure how you do this with mPDF) the point is to output the file from script directly into the browser. It's something like this:

```
 <?php 
     $x = some_function($_GET['param1'],$_GET['param2', ...); // PDF GEN. ROUTINE, BASED ON REQUEST DATA, HOWEVER YOU DO IT
     header('Content-type: application/pdf');
     echo $x;
```

That should solve all your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend you to generate a different temp file for each generated PDF, in order to avoid any possible error like one user downloading somebody else's PDF, etc.

To clean up the temp directory, I'd use a cronjob that deletes all files older than N days.

In order to "force save dialog", you have to set the `Content-disposition` header to `attachment`:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.pdf"');
```